# MS Word 2010 - how to create simple bibliography to reference it

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink, cross-reference, reference-book

I want to create simple bibliography that would be sorted by authors name and would be with numbered links. But I have problems doing that. I tried using bibliography feature in a Word, but it strangely adds sources. For example I added some book and it adds like this (I tried various styles, but every style adds () and didn't see a way to make it numbered):

(Author, Something)

I want it to look like it is in most articles, simply like this:

**My text**

My text I refer to some book [1]. Another reference [2]. And some other reference to same book again [1].

**References**

```
[1] Author1, Book name1
[2] Author2, Book name2
```

How could I do this (and if I pressed on [1] in text, it should jump to referenced book. The same as in Wikipedia)?

The only way I managed to do with was using endnotes, but it does not let me use [] brackets and also I can't reference to same book twice (or maybe I don't know how), I have to create another endnote which creates new number (even if I don't need one, because I'm referring to same book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for bookmarks. With them you will be able to jump up and down the document and simulate the "wikipedia behavior" you want.
Here is a more detailed article about it: **[Add or delete bookmarks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-or-delete-bookmarks-HP001226532.aspx)**

Essentially you go to Insert tab > Links > type a name for your bookmark and add it. Later on you go to same place and select the bookmark you created and hit "go to".

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the closest thing I need. Is it possible to make it automatically numbered? So for example if add another bookmark in between other bookmarks, it would automatically assign proper number for it. Now I see I need to manually enter numbering. And later I will need to modify manually alot if it wont adjust like this: [1] book1, [2] book2. Then let say I want to add another book that by ordering is second book, so it should adjust numbering like this: [1] book1, [2] book3, [3] book2.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.lse.ac.uk/intranet/LSEServices/IMT/guides/softwareGuides/office2010/Word-2010-Reference.aspx

Comment: I found how to do the way I wanted by this example: http://www.sylvienoel.ca/blog/?p=180